# Regex javascript tuning

Tags: javascript, regex

First steps in regex and been trying to get some values out of emails that are being fetched. So far I've achieved some (even if it's not with the best approach) but in need of some more values and can't figure out how to get them.

This is the email template that is more or less always the same:

```
London, 06/20/09

Mr. Tom Waits

Process ref.: CR // 1943061

Your reference: 338256

Clients' names: Mary Lamb, John Snow

We return to your contact regarding the complaint on behalf of the clients mentioned above.

We inform you that the refund process has already started, so you should receive the respective amount (375EUR) within 4/6 weeks.

Payment ref.: 2500062960.

Our compliments,(...)
```

WHAT I NEED:

- Date after "London,"
- Process ref. (2 letters + // + digits)
- Your ref. number
- Clients' names
- Amount
- Payment reference number

*Notes* the amount not always comes between "( )", sometimes it's preceeded by "amount" others by "amount of", sometimes "EUR" is separated by a space, but the needed value is always the first digits combination on the paragraph

WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:

```
(?:London,)(.*)\s+(?:Mr. Tom Waits)\s+(?:Process ref.:)\s+(....\d+)\s+(?:Your reference:)\s+(\d+)\s+(?:Clients' names:)\s+(.*)\s+
```

WHAT IT RETRIEVES:

- Date after "London,"
- Process ref. (2 letters + // + digits)
- Your reference number
- Clients' names

WHAT'S MISSING:

- Amount
- Payment reference number

Other Concerns:

- I tried to exclude the "Mr" parapraph but I think there may be a problem when they write it a little different like with an extra space or something
- The same problem may arise if they also write the items a little different like, for example, "Process reference" instead of "Process ref."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extracting all these fields with a single regex is a bad idea IMO. If you insist on using regexes, better run on the letter, line by line, and parse each case separately.

Comment: Something like /^\D+amount\D+(\d+)/i should catch the amount, if you process the text line by line; wich, even in my opinion, is a better idea. You may need to change it to get decimals, if present.

Comment: A crude [example](https://regex101.com/r/RDf7Cx/1)

Comment: First, thank you all for the help. I've tested your "crude example", JvdV, and it seems simpler than mine indeed but I would still have the same problems, since the amount is not always between parentesis but is also the first digit combination on the paragraph (also I don't need the currency "EUR") and the emails may vary a litlle on the items, as I mentioned on my post (e.g. Process ref. may be Process reference:). I also tried to incorporate the Giovanni Zezza bit on your example but with no luck. As a sidenote, I'm using this on a google app script to parse some emails from gmail

Comment: As I said, my example works if you process the text line by line (or maybe with the multiline 'm' flag): the initial '^' means 'at the beginning of the line'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's gonna be one hefty regex. I do hope you don't try this regex on a massive file but rather one singular entry (like the one you've shown in your post).

Anyway, here's the regex-

```regex
London, ([\d\/]+)[\n\w\W]*?Process ref(?:\.|erence): ([A-Z \/\d]+)[\n\w\W]*?Your ref(?:\.|erence): (\d+)[\n\w\W]*?Client(?:s'|'s) name(?:s)?: ([\w ,]+)[\n\w\W]*?amount.*?(\d+)[\n\w\W]*?Payment ref(?:\.|erence): (\d+)
```

This should be quite permissive, it doesn't depend on many variable (seemingly) things, apart from `London`, that one's a bit of a hard coding but I'm assuming it's always `London`.

Now, let's walk through this-

- `London, ([\d\/]+)` - This basically matches `London, DATE` - where date is, well, a date, where each element of the date is separated by a `/`.

  In this case, it matches `06/20/09` from `London, 06/20/09`
- `[\n\w\W]*?` - Try to keep up with this one - I'm using it a A LOT.

  This will match pretty much all new lines, word characters and non word characters in a non-greedy way. In this particular case, this will match pretty much **everything** and that includes the newlines. This is used to just skip over anything and everything until we reach the desired spot.
- `Process ref(?:\.|erence): ([A-Z \/\d]+)` - Captures the process reference, which can consist of capital alphabets (I assume, you can change that), slashes (`/`), and digits

  Works with both `ref.` and `reference`

  In this case, it matches `CR // 1943061`, from `Process ref.: CR // 1943061`
- `[\n\w\W]*?` - Ignore everything up until the next token
- `Your ref(?:\.|erence): (\d+)` - Captures "your reference", which can consist of digits

  Works with both `ref.` and `reference`

  In this case, it matches `338256`
- `[\n\w\W]*?` - Ignore everything up until the next token
- `Client(?:s'|'s) name(?:s)?: ([\w ,]+)` - Captures the client name(s) - modified so it supports single client names too. (check the demo). The name list can consist of word characters, spaces and a comma.

  In this case, it captures `Mary Lamb, John Snow`, from `Clients' names: Mary Lamb, John Snow`
- `(\d+)` - Capture the digits - this is a big assumption, I'm assuming that the only digits that appear after client name list, are the ones for the amount. If they aren't
- `[\n\w\W]*?` - Ignore everything up until the next token
- `amount.*?(\d+)` - Captures the first group of digits that appear after `amount`. This is a bit of an assumption, I'm assuming that `amount` word is actually present in that paragraph.

  In this case, it captures `375`, from `amount (375EUR)`
- `[\n\w\W]*?` - Ignore everything up until the next token
- `Payment ref(?:\.|erence): (\d+)` - Capture the Payment reference number, which can consist of digits

  Works with both `ref.` and `reference`

  In this case, it captures `2500062960`, from `Payment ref.: 2500062960.`

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/02AJuf/2)!

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a great lesson on regex which was what I was aiming for also. Since the original email is on a different language than the one I used here, it was a good exercice to understand the code as I adapted it to the original language and remembered some more variables. I took into consideration the concerns about the complexity of the regex but it will parse some emails that we get 1 time per month so I think/hope it will be ok.

Comment: do you think it's possible to account for the possibility that Payment Ref line does not exist or either the digits or the item name? This is the code I've adapted from you: `L(?:.*), ?([\d\S\,]+)[\n\w\W]*?Pro(?:.*:) ?([ A-Z \/\d]+)?[\n\w\W]*?Your(?:.*:) ?(\d+)?[\n\w\W]*?Client(?:.*:) ?([\w a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÒÖÚÇÑ., ]+)?[\n\w\W]*?amount.*?(\d+[\w ., ]\d+)[\n\w\W]*?Pay(?:.*:)? ?(\d+)?`. It does allow me to delete either the item name or the number itself but I can't delete the all line and keep the regex valid. <https://regex101.com/r/0JBJQ1/2>

Comment: @user1128912 please provide an example paragraph and example output, preferably in a separate question

Comment: It was for the parsing of the same text, as an extra request, that's why I've used the same post but I will create a new one. Thanks

Comment: I got this to work using (just going to post a short version): `amount.*?(\d+[\w ., ]\d+)[\n\w\W]*(?:weeks|signed)[.\s\n]\s*(?:Pay(?:.*:))? ?(\d+)?`. I've noticed that when the string is not on the email, the last word of the previous paragraph also changes. I had really tried lots of versions but new day, fresh thoughts :) I also created another post but deleted it and decided to add here the answer to keep it all together.

Comment: In: `amount.*?(\d+[\w ., ]\d+)` '.*?' and '[\w ., ]' match too much things; I think you need only `amount\D*(\d+[.,]\d+)` That is, some not numeric character after 'amount', then a number, a point or a comma, another number. Also, this way there has to be a decimal part; in your example there was 'amount (375EUR)' without decimals. I think you may need alternation (the | symbol) on two expressions to catch both. Other expressions can be simplified: [\w\W] that means word and not-word character, that is everything; you don't have to add the \n, it's allready here.